# Complexity from a recent exam that confused people

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o, complexity-theory

Do you think the following information is true?

```
If Θ(f(n)) = Θ(g(n)) AND g(n) > 0 everywhere THEN f(n)/g(n) ∈ Θ(1)
```

We are having bit of argument with our prof

Comment: And what is your contention as to the statement above? And what does your prof say?

Comment: The answer in exam is 'false'. We are arguing that it is 'true'. After the following comments, I feel like our Prof might have miscalculated.

Comment: I agree with your professor. You have no information which says that evaluating `f` and `g` takes constant time for all `n`.

Comment: @Bob It doesn't have to, it needs to grow at the same rate. Take any `g(n) = f(n)`, division result will be `1`.

Comment: If it's false, your professor should be able to show you a concrete counterexample.

Comment: If it's false, your professor should be able to show you the mistake in the proof you were using as an argument of its correctness.

Comment: @PaulHankin Perhaps it was a true/false question, with no argument or proof required.

Comment: @pjs Ahmet says he was arguing with the prof about the answer. So I assume Ahmet has a proof.

Comment: @PaulHankin After your answer he certainly does.

Comment: thanks everyone for your comments. I would like to share your comments with the prof and will let you know if he actually changes his mind. Beware that he is a notorious professor for preparing one of the top programming teams in the world so it would be pretty funny if he is actually wrong for once.

Comment: What definition of Ω does your prof use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

f(n) = Θ(g(n)) means there's c, d, n0 such that cg(n) <= f(n) <= dg(n) for n > n0.

Then, since g(n) > 0, c <= f(n)/g(n) <= d for n > n0.

So f(n)/g(n) = Θ(1).

Answer (score 0):

Dividing functions `f(n),g(n)` is not the same as dividing their Big-O. For example let:

```
f(n) = n^3 + n^2 + n
g(n) = n^3
```

so:

```
O(f(n)) = n^3
O(g(n)) = n^3
```

but:

```
f(n)/g(n) = 1 + 1/n + 1/n^2 != constant !!!
```

**[Edit1]**

but as **kfx** pointed you are comparing with complexity so you want:

```
O(f(n)/g(n)) = O(1 + 1/n + 1/n^2) = O(1)
```

**So the answer is Yes.**

But beware complexity theory is not really my cup of tea and also I do not have any context to the question of yours.

Comment: The function `1 + 1/n + 1/n^2` is bounded by a constant, so it's Θ(1).

Comment: @kfx youre right the catch is in the comparison so we need to take Big O of the result instead of raw result ... (have repaired answer accordingly)

Answer (score 0):

Using definitions for Landau notation https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation, it's easy to conclude that this is true, the limit of division must be less than infinity but larger than 0.

It does not have to be exactly `1` but it has to be a finite constant, which is Θ(1).

A counter example would be nice, and should be easy to be given if the statement isn't true. A positive rigorous proof would probably need to go from definition of limes with respect to series, to prove equivalence of formal and limit definitions.

I use this definition and haven't seen it proven wrong. I suppose the disagreement might lie in exact definition of Θ, it is known that people use those colloquially with minor differences, especially Big O. Or maybe some tricky cases. For positively defined functions and series, I don't think it fails.

Answer (score 0):

Basically there are three options for any pair of functions `f, g`: Either the first grows *asymptotically* slower and we write `f=o(g)` (notice I'm using small o), the first grows *asymptotically* faster: `f=ω(g)` (again, small omega) or they are asymptotically tightly bound: `f=Θ(g)`.

What `f=o(g)` means is stricter then big O in that it doesn't allow for `f=Θ(g)` to be true; `f=Θ(g)` implies both `f=O(g)` and `f=Ω(g)`, but `o, Θ` and `ω` are exclusive.

To find out whether `f=o(g)` it's sufficient to evaluate limit for n going to infinity `f(n)/g(n)` and if it is zero, `f=o(g)` is true, if it is infinity `f=ω(g)` is true and if it is any real finite number, `f=Θ(g)` is your answer. **This is not a definition**, but merely a way to evaluate a statement. (One assumption I made here was that both f and g are positive.)

Special case is if limit for n goint to infinity `f(n)/1 = f(n)` is finite number, it means `f(n)=Θ(1)` (basically we chose constant function for `g`).

Now we're getting to your problem: Since `f=g(Θ)`implies `f=O(g)`, we know that there exists `c>0` and `n0` such that `f(n) <= c*g(n)`for all `n>n0`. Thus we know that `f(n)/g(n) <= (c*g(n))/g(n) = c`for all `n>n0`. The same can be done for `Ω` just with opposite unequality signs. Thus we get that `f(n)/g(n)`is between `c1`and `c2` from some `n0` which are known to be finite numbers because of how `Θ` is defined. Because we know our new function is somewhere in there we also know that its limit is finite number, thus proving it is indeed constant.

Conclusion, I believe you were right and I would like your professor to offer counterexample to dispruve the statement. If something didn't make sense feel free to ask more in the comments, I'll try to clarify.